# Template vector struct in C11

Tags: c, template, vectors, macros, c11

This one review will be a little bit tricky: I was trying to implement a template `Vector` struct in C11. Of course, templates don't really exist in C11, so I used *a few* macros to get the desired interface. Here is the implementation of the core features, trying to mimick those of the c++ `std::vector`. Some are still missing though. First, the macro `define_Vector`:

```
#define define_Vector(T)                                                  \
                                                                          \
    struct _vector_##T;                                                   \
                                                                          \
    typedef struct                                                        \
    {                                                                     \
        void (*delete)(struct _vector_##T*);                              \
        T (*at)(const struct _vector_##T*, size_t);                       \
        T (*front)(const struct _vector_##T*);                            \
        T (*back)(const struct _vector_##T*);                             \
        T* (*data)(const struct _vector_##T*);                            \
        T* (*begin)(struct _vector_##T*);                                 \
        const T* (*cbegin)(const struct _vector_##T*);                    \
        T* (*end)(struct _vector_##T*);                                   \
        const T* (*cend)(const struct _vector_##T*);                      \
        bool (*is_empty)(const struct _vector_##T*);                      \
        size_t (*size)(const struct _vector_##T*);                        \
        size_t (*max_size)(void);                                         \
        void (*reserve)(struct _vector_##T*, size_t);                     \
        size_t (*capacity)(const struct _vector_##T*);                    \
        void (*shrink_to_fit)(struct _vector_##T*);                       \
        void (*clear)(struct _vector_##T*);                               \
        void (*erase1)(struct _vector_##T*, const T*);                    \
        void (*erase2)(struct _vector_##T*, const T*, const T*);          \
        void (*push_back)(struct _vector_##T*, T);                        \
        void (*pop_back)(struct _vector_##T*);                            \
        void (*resize1)(struct _vector_##T*, size_t);                     \
        void (*resize2)(struct _vector_##T*, size_t, T);                  \
    } _vector_functions_##T;                                              \
                                                                          \
    typedef struct _vector_##T                                            \
    {                                                                     \
        T* _data;                                                         \
        size_t _size;                                                     \
        size_t _capacity;                                                 \
        const _vector_functions_##T* _functions;                          \
    } Vector_##T;                                                         \
                                                                          \
Vector_##T* new_Vector_##T();                                             \
void vector_delete_##T(Vector_##T*);                                      \
T vector_at_##T(const Vector_##T*, size_t);                               \
T vector_front_##T(const Vector_##T*);                                    \
T vector_back_##T(const Vector_##T*);                                     \
T* vector_data_##T(const Vector_##T*);                                    \
T* vector_begin_##T(Vector_##T*);                                         \
const T* vector_cbegin_##T(const Vector_##T*);                            \
T* vector_end_##T(Vector_##T*);                                           \
const T* vector_cend_##T(const Vector_##T*);                              \
bool vector_is_empty_##T(const Vector_##T*);                              \
size_t vector_size_##T(const Vector_##T*);                                \
size_t vector_max_size_##T(void);                                         \
void vector_reserve_##T(Vector_##T*, size_t);                             \
size_t vector_capacity_##T(const Vector_##T*);                            \
void vector_shrink_to_fit_##T(Vector_##T*);                               \
void vector_clear_##T(Vector_##T*);                                       \
void vector_erase1_##T(Vector_##T*, const T*);                            \
void vector_erase2_##T(Vector_##T*, const T*, const T*);                  \
void vector_push_back_##T(Vector_##T*, T);                                \
void vector_pop_back_##T(Vector_##T*);                                    \
void vector_resize1_##T(Vector_##T*, size_t);                             \
void vector_resize2_##T(Vector_##T*, size_t, T);                          \
                                                                          \
void vector_delete_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                                \
{                                                                         \
    free(vector->_data);                                                  \
    free(vector);                                                         \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T vector_at_##T(const Vector_##T* vector, size_t index)                   \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_data[index];                                          \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T vector_front_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                              \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_data[0];                                              \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T vector_back_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                               \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_data[size(vector)-1];                                 \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T* vector_data_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                              \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_data;                                                 \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T* vector_begin_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                                   \
{                                                                         \
    return data(vector);                                                  \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
const T* vector_cbegin_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                      \
{                                                                         \
    return data(vector);                                                  \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
T* vector_end_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                                     \
{                                                                         \
    return data(vector) + size(vector);                                   \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
const T* vector_cend_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                        \
{                                                                         \
    return data(vector) + size(vector);                                   \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
bool vector_is_empty_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                        \
{                                                                         \
    return size(vector) == 0;                                             \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
size_t vector_size_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                          \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_size;                                                 \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
size_t vector_max_size_##T(void)                                          \
{                                                                         \
    return SIZE_MAX;                                                      \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
void vector_reserve_##T(Vector_##T* vector, size_t new_cap)               \
{                                                                         \
    if (new_cap > capacity(vector))                                       \
    {                                                                     \
        vector->_capacity = new_cap;                                      \
        vector->_data = realloc(vector->_data,                            \
                                new_cap * sizeof(T));                     \
    }                                                                     \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
size_t vector_capacity_##T(const Vector_##T* vector)                      \
{                                                                         \
    return vector->_capacity;                                             \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
void vector_shrink_to_fit_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                         \
{                                                                         \
    vector->_capacity = size(vector);                                     \
    vector->_data = realloc(vector->_data,                                \
                            size(vector) * sizeof(T));                    \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
void vector_clear_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                                 \
{                                                                         \
    vector->_size = 0;                                                    \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
void vector_erase1_##T(Vector_##T* vector, const T* pos)                  \
{                                                                         \
    T* it = (T*) pos;                                                     \
    while (it != end(vector)-1)                                           \
    {                                                                     \
        *it = it[1];                                                      \
        ++it;                                                             \
    }                                                                     \
    --vector->_size;                                                      \
}                                                                         \
                                                                          \
void vector_erase2_##T(Vector_##T* vector, const T* first, const T* last) \
{                                                                  \
    T* it1 = (T*) first;                                           \
    T* it2 = (T*) last;                                            \
    while (it2 != end(vector))                                     \
    {                                                              \
        *it1 = *it2;                                               \
        ++it1;                                                     \
        ++it2;                                                     \
    }                                                              \
    vector->_size -= last-first;                                   \
}                                                                  \
                                                                   \
void vector_push_back_##T(Vector_##T* vector, T value)             \
{                                                                  \
    vector->_size += 1;                                            \
    if (capacity(vector) < size(vector))                           \
    {                                                              \
        reserve(vector, capacity(vector)+40);                      \
    }                                                              \
    last(vector) = value;                                          \
}                                                                  \
                                                                   \
void vector_pop_back_##T(Vector_##T* vector)                       \
{                                                                  \
    if (size(vector) > 0)                                          \
    {                                                              \
        vector->_size -= 1;                                        \
    }                                                              \
}                                                                  \
                                                                   \
void vector_resize1_##T(Vector_##T* vector, size_t count)          \
{                                                                  \
    if (count < size(vector))                                      \
    {                                                              \
        while (size(vector) > count)                               \
        {                                                          \
            pop_back(vector);                                      \
        }                                                          \
    }                                                              \
    else                                                           \
    {                                                              \
        reserve(vector, count);                                    \
        vector->_size = count;                                     \
    }                                                              \
}                                                                  \
                                                                   \
void vector_resize2_##T(Vector_##T* vector, size_t count, T value) \
{                                                                  \
    if (count < size(vector))                                      \
    {                                                              \
        while (size(vector) > count)                               \
        {                                                          \
            pop_back(vector);                                      \
        }                                                          \
    }                                                              \
    else                                                           \
    {                                                              \
        while (size(vector) < count)                               \
        {                                                          \
            push_back(vector, value);                              \
        }                                                          \
    }                                                              \
}                                                                  \
                                                                   \
const _vector_functions_##T _vector_funcs_##T = {                  \
    &vector_delete_##T,                                            \
    &vector_at_##T,                                                \
    &vector_front_##T,                                             \
    &vector_back_##T,                                              \
    &vector_data_##T,                                              \
    &vector_begin_##T,                                             \
    &vector_cbegin_##T,                                            \
    &vector_end_##T,                                               \
    &vector_cend_##T,                                              \
    &vector_is_empty_##T,                                          \
    &vector_size_##T,                                              \
    &vector_max_size_##T,                                          \
    &vector_reserve_##T,                                           \
    &vector_capacity_##T,                                          \
    &vector_shrink_to_fit_##T,                                     \
    &vector_clear_##T,                                             \
    &vector_erase1_##T,                                            \
    &vector_erase2_##T,                                            \
    &vector_push_back_##T,                                         \
    &vector_pop_back_##T,                                          \
    &vector_resize1_##T,                                           \
    &vector_resize2_##T,                                           \
};                                                                 \
                                                                   \
Vector_##T* new_Vector_##T()                                       \
{                                                                  \
    Vector_##T* res = malloc(sizeof(Vector_##T));                  \
    res->_functions = &_vector_funcs_##T;                          \
    res->_capacity = 40;                                           \
    res->_size = 0;                                                \
    res->_data = malloc(40*sizeof(T));                             \
    return res;                                                    \
}
```

To access the functions contained in the global struct, I use the following macros (some also provide extra features):

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Element access

#define at(collection, index) \
        collection->_functions->at(collection, index)

#define front(collection) \
        collection->_functions->front(collection)

#define back(collection) \
        collection->_functions->back(collection)

#define data(collection) \
        collection->_functions->data(collection)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Iterators

#define begin(collection) \
        collection->_functions->begin(collection)

#define cbegin(collection) \
        collection->_functions->cbegin(collection)

#define end(collection) \
        collection->_functions->end(collection)

#define cend(collection) \
        collection->_functions->cend(collection)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Capacity

#define is_empty(collection) \
        collection->_functions->is_empty(collection)

#define size(collection) \
        collection->_functions->size(collection)

#define max_size(collection) \
        collection->_functions->max_size()

#define reserve(collection, new_cap) \
        collection->_functions->reserve(collection, new_cap)

#define capacity(collection) \
        collection->_functions->capacity(collection)

#define shrink_to_fit(collection) \
        collection->_functions->shrink_to_fit(collection)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Modifiers

#define clear(collection) \
        collection->_functions->clear(collection)

#define erase(collection, ...) \
        DISPATCH(erase, __VA_ARGS__)(collection, __VA_ARGS__)
#define erase1(collection, pos) \
        collection->_functions->erase1(collection, pos)
#define erase2(collection, first, last) \
        collection->_functions->erase2(collection, first, last)

#define push_back(collection, elem) \
        collection->_functions->push_back(collection, elem)

#define pop_back(collection) \
        collection->_functions->pop_back(collection)

#define resize(collection, ...) \
        DISPATCH(resize, __VA_ARGS__)(collection, __VA_ARGS__)
#define resize1(collection, count) \
        collection->_functions->resize1(collection, count)
#define resize2(collection, count, value) \
        collection->_functions->resize2(collection, count, value)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Macros to improve usability

/**
 * @def define(type)
 * Defines all the functions for the given type.
 */
#define define(type) \
        define_##type

/**
 * @def new(type)
 * Creates a new instance of the given type and
 * returns a pointer to it.
 */
#define new(type) \
        new_##type

/**
 * @def delete(collection)
 * Calls the class "destructor" to free what has
 * to be freed.
 */
#define delete(collection) \
        collection->_functions->delete(collection)

/**
 * @def elem(collection, index)
 * Returns the given element of a contiguous collection.
 */
#define elem(collection, index) \
        data(collection)[index]

/**
 * @def first(collection)
 * Returns the first element of a contiguous collection.
 */
#define first(collection) \
        data(collection)[0]

/**
 * @def last(collection)
 * Returns the last element of a contiguous collection.
 */
#define last(collection) \
        data(collection)[size(collection)-1]
```

And here are the macros - only well-known macros - used to implement the interface macros:

```
// Some compilers need one more level of indirection
// than GCC, hence PASTE_3.
#define PASTE_3(x, y) \
    x ## y
#define PASTE_2(x, y) \
    PASTE_3(x, y)
#define PASTE_1(x, y) \
    PASTE_2(x, y)

// DISPATCH cannot use VA_NARGS because of the
// sizeof check. Therefore, it uses the version
// which cannot handle the 0.
#define VA_NARGS_2(_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9, _10, _11, _12, _13, _14, _15, N, ...) \
    N
// Note: the last dummy parameter sole purpose is
// to avoid a warning
#define VA_NARGS_1(...) \
    VA_NARGS_2(__VA_ARGS__, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, /* dummy */)

/**
 * @def PASTE(x, y)
 * Pastes two macros tokens together to create
 * a new name.
 */
#define PASTE(x, y) \
    PASTE_1(x, y)

/**
 * @def VA_NARGS(...)
 * Counts the number of arguments of the given
 * macro parameter pack.
 */
#define VA_NARGS(...) \
    sizeof(#__VA_ARGS__) == sizeof("") ? 0 : \
    VA_NARGS_1(__VA_ARGS__)

/**
 * @def DISPATCH(func, ...)
 * Calls different functions in function of the
 * number of parameters in the parameter pack.
 * Therefore, it allows to overload macros based
 * on the number of arguments passed to it.
 *
 * @warning Can not handle 0-sized parameter packs.
 */
#define DISPATCH(func, ...) \
    PASTE(func, VA_NARGS_1(__VA_ARGS__))
```

And finally, here is an example of how to use all the code above:

```
define(Vector(float))
define(Vector(int))
define(Vector(double))

int main()
{
    Vector(int)* vec_i = new(Vector(int));
    Vector(double)* vec_d = new(Vector(double));

    printf("is_empty: %d\n", is_empty(vec_i));
    printf("size: %u\n", size(vec_i));
    printf("max_size: %u\n", max_size(vec_i));
    printf("capacity: %u\n", capacity(vec_i));
    printf("front: %d == %d\n", front(vec_i), at(vec_i, 0));
    printf("back: %d == %d\n", back(vec_i), at(vec_i, 2));

    reserve(vec_d, 56);
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_d)); // 56
    reserve(vec_d, 30);
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_d)); // 56

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
    {
        push_back(vec_d, 0.0);
    }
    first(vec_d) = 5.6;
    elem(vec_d, 1) = 1.0;
    elem(vec_d, 2) = 2.0;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
    {
        printf("%f ", at(vec_d, i));
    }
    printf("\n");

    shrink_to_fit(vec_d);
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_d)); // 3

    assert(data(vec_d) == vec_d->_data);
    assert(last(vec_d) == elem(vec_d, 2));

    for (int i = 5 ; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        push_back(vec_i, i);
    }
    printf("size: %u\n", size(vec_i)); // 5
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_i)); // 40
    pop_back(vec_i);
    pop_back(vec_i);
    shrink_to_fit(vec_i);
    printf("size: %u\n", size(vec_i)); // 3
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_i)); // 3
    int foo = 8;
    push_back(vec_i, foo);
    printf("size: %u\n", size(vec_i)); // 4
    printf("capacity: %d\n", capacity(vec_i)); // 43

    delete(vec_i);
    delete(vec_d);

    // erase methods
    Vector(int)* vi = new(Vector(int));
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        push_back(vi, i);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for (int* it = begin(vi) ; it != end(vi) ; ++it)
    {
        // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        printf("%d ", *it);
    }

    printf("\n");
    erase(vi, begin(vi));
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size(vi) ; ++i)
    {
        // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        printf("%d ", at(vi, i));
    }

    printf("\n");
    erase(vi, begin(vi)+2, begin(vi)+5);
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size(vi) ; ++i)
    {
        // 1 2 6 7 8 9
        printf("%d ", at(vi, i));
    }

    delete(vi);
}
```

Of course, none of this is meant to be used with a C++ compiler and all this code is merely done for fun; I would never use that as production code. Also, I already know that all those macros pollute everything, but I don't care - all of this is just a proof of concept. So, would there be any way to improve the interface even further? Moreover, are there ovious errors in the `Vector` implementation?

Comment: Interesting, however the implementation is by force of nature of cpp not so appealing as it should. I think somebody should develop more powerful and elegant macro/templating language which to use to write this kind of stuff, and then compile that hand-edited file to C and to object code. This is easily to automated if you use `make` or a similar tool. Omitting desire for syntactic sugar, `eperl`, `eruby` would be easy grounds of experimentation about what this thing would like to look like.

Comment: What C11 features are you actually using? It seems to compile just fine as C99.

Comment: @200_success It indeed does compile in C99. But I would be glad to know whether it could be improved with C11; I don't want to limit myself to C99.

Comment: I suggest to use generic list implementation of Rusty Russels (used in Linux kernel). It does not need all this preprocessor code. See http://ccodearchive.net/info/list.html.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a rather large amount of code here and a lot of macro trickery, so I shall refrain from attempting to comment on it all.

There are, however, a few things that immediately jumped out at me.

---

Don't use `new` as your allocating macro. That's extremely confusing, and it's going to make compiling it as C++ rather difficult. (Not that having C be compilable as C++ is exactly a noble goal -- it's just not worth throwing away over one word).

---

Your macros should be namespaced. `size`? `at`? You don't think anyone else might try to use those names?

Rather than `define_Vector` have `vector_define` and then `vector_at`, `vector_size`, etc. Not only does this make it immediately clearer that things like `size` aren't some kind of magic, it should hopefully help avoid potential collisions if someone were to use this with other code.

---

`realloc` can fail. You need to consider that in `vector_reserve`, `vector_shrink_to_fit` and so on.

---

Are you sure your accessors (`vector_at`, `vector_front`, etc) should return a `T` and not a `T*`? Imagine if you're storing a large struct. You would probably rather be able to mutate the struct inside of the vector rather than having to copy it, modify it, and then put it back. (Yes, you can get direct access like this with your 'iterators', but eh...).

---

This feels a bit incomplete if you're trying to mimic C++. Where are constructors? Destructors? Copiers? What if I have a vector of 10 structs that have FILE* pointers? It would be nice to be able to assign a destructor to those so that calls like `vector_clear` would not leave a dangling file handle.

---

I actually might consider going with `T` here like you've done, but it's fairly customary in C to use an automatic form of `sizeof` rather than explicit. Like:

```
res->_data = malloc(40*sizeof(*(res->data)));
```

---

Accepting constant pointers rather than values in a few places would allow you to avoid potential copies. Unfortunately that makes the calling semantics a bit grosser, but welcome to C :).

---

40 is a rather large default capacity. (Also, you *have* to handle malloc/realloc failures for a library like this.)

It would be nice to be able to avoid a malloc until something is actually stored in the vector. It could avoid a rather costly allocation in certain cases where a vector is created and then not pushed into.

---

I might try to pull the default capacity into a constant or something, but either way, it shouldn't be repeated:

```
res->_capacity = 40;                                           \
res->_size = 0;                                                \
res->_data = malloc(40*sizeof(T));
```

Could be:

```
res->_capacity = 40;                                           \
res->_size = 0;                                                \
res->_data = malloc(res->_capacity*sizeof(T));
```

This is just to avoid a mismatch if at some point 40 is changed on one line and not the other.

---

*Unsolicited, blatant opinion incoming :)*

Though this is elegant and clever, overall I'm not sure how I feel about it.

As you almost certainly know, data structures in C typically revolve around `void*` with a complete lack of type safety. Your vector give type safety at a relatively minor cost (binary size), so that's rather nice and a very real benefit.

I can't help but feel though that at the end of the day, you've just recreated templates in a language not meant to support them. In almost all situations where this would be used, I think the proper option would be to just use C++. Then again, I'm **very** biased towards C++, and my sentiment is almost always "if you *can* use C++, then you **should** use C++."

In situations where you're stuck using C, this could be very valuable if type safety is very important. I do believe though that it would require a bit more polishing in terms of the items mentioned above, and it would need to be tested very thoroughly in both functional and performance senses.

Comment: The goal was indeed to "recreate templates in C" (as said in the introduction), and also to create a basic set of features meant to be built upon later. It was not meant to be integrated to any actual project. Using unnamespaced names was part of the design (using c++ keywords was also part of it); also, the "interface" macros can match any other collections with the required functions.

Comment: @Morwenn Ah :). I would still highly suggest against un-namespaced names or C++ keywords though. Just go with something more general like `container_` and something with a similar meaning but a non-keyword like `create` or `delete`. I guess if you're determined to mimic C++ as closely as possible, I can see where you're coming from, but unless this is purely academic, mimicking a language for the sake of mimicking a language is dubious.

Comment: I generally use C++ (ok, always use it actually). This was nothing but an exercise to see how far I could push a plain *new* C. Concerning the constructor and destructor, those are `vector_delete_##T` and `new_Vector_##T`. I totally do lack a copier and a mean to compare the vectors though...

Comment: Overall, your comments are valuable though. And you're right, having `container_*` or `collection_*` is not that heavy and still quite generic :)

Comment: @Morwenn I meant a ctor/dtor for the elements, not the container. It would of course be a bit awkward though since the constructor/destructor would be attached to the container rather than the stored `struct`. A case could certainly be made for the "you're expected to clean stuff up manually before disposing of a vector or any elements" route.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I totally overlooked that. If meant to be built upon, I could require users to have destructors (`mytype_delete`) and call `delete` in `vector_delete_mytype`. Since there isn't such a thing for built-in types, I could probably `_Generic` away those types in the implementation of `delete`.

Comment: @Morwenn Yeah. I would be tempted to implement it as just a simple function pointer stored in the vector instance. That would allow the consumer to theoretically customize it to be whatever they wanted to be named, but in the case that a dtor wasn't provided to the vector constructor it could default to either no constructor, or you could use compiler specific tricks to look for an optional `type_delete`. That might get very gross though, and the flexibility would probably go unused. Probably better to do as you said and just require `delete_*` unless rather interesting use were expected.

Answer (score 7):

I did manage to improve some things since the question was posted. So here is what I discovered, that could somehow improve the implementation and the usability of the `Vector(T)`:

- First of all, there was an error in the code. *Shame on me*. I shared a piece of code that could not be compiled. I must have posted a version that was not up-to-date. The macro `new` does not work for two reasons: the token pasting is not well done ***and*** I forgot to add the parenthesis for the function call. The first solution to fix that error is to have `new(Vector(int))` call `new_Vector_int()`:

  ```
  #define new(type) \
      PASTE(new_, type)()
  ```

  The second solution is to have `new(Vector(int))` resolve to `new_Vector_int` and add the call by hand on the calling site. This would allow to "overload constructors":

  ```
  #define new(type) \
      PASTE(new_, type)

  Vector(int)* vec_i = new(Vector(int))(/* maybe more paremeters later */);
  ```
- The `define_vector_##T` macro introduces names that begin with an underscore in the global scope. Such names are reserved to the implementation; they should either use another prefix or be put somewhere else (for example, the function table could be a `static` variable in a function. Not that this is a good idea either, but you get it...).
- The `typedef` between `struct _vector_##T` and `Vector_##T` is done quite late. I could have used the "forward `typedef`":

  ```
  typedef struct _vector_##T Vector_##T;
  ```

  This would have allowed me use `Vector_##T` instead of `struct _vector_##T` in the function declarations.
- Actually, I can also use `Vector(T)` directly instead of `Vector_##T` in the body of `define_Vector`. Thanks to that, I can drop many `##` operators and the code ends up being easier to read.
- The macros parameters are not always correctly guarded with parenthesis. If I have a stack-allocated vector and try to give its address to a function (*e.g.* `begin(&vec_i)`), it fails miserably. More parenthesis are needed:

  ```
  #define begin(collection) \
          (collection)->_functions->begin(collection)
  ```
- Last but not least, I kind of failed (at first) to mimic the C++ functions returning lvalues (non-`const` references). I can still work around that by having the functions return pointers and having the interface macros dereference those functions returns. Take the example of `front`. The declaration becomes:

  ```
  T* vector_front_##T(const Vector(T)*);
  ```

  The definition becomes:

  ```
  T* vector_front_##T(const Vector(T)* vector)
  {
      return vector->_data;
  }
  ```

  And the macro `front` becomes:

  ```
  #define front(collection) \
      (*((collection)->_functions->front(collection)))
  ```

  This new trick allows us to get rid of the workaround macros `elem`, `first` and `last` since `at`, `front` and `back` can now somehow return lvalues instead of simple values, and not only for data structures with contiguous storage. Of all the points, this is the only one that allows to increase the usability of the code.